lightgbm.basic.LightGBMError: Check failed: (best_split_info.left_count) > (0)
I have a training script for Lgbm with cpu that runs fine with these hyperparameters:
    'objective': 'binary',
    'metric': 'auc',
    'boosting_type': 'gbdt',
    'verbosity': -1,
    'max_depth': trial.suggest_int('max_depth', 10, 20),
    'num_leaves': trial.suggest_int('num_leaves', 150, 250),
    'learning_rate': trial.suggest_float('learning_rate', 0.03, 0.1, log=True),
    'feature_fraction': trial.suggest_float('feature_fraction', 0.2, 0.8),
    'bagging_fraction': trial.suggest_float('bagging_fraction', 0.2, 1.0),
    'min_child_weight': trial.suggest_float('min_child_weight', 1e-3, 10.0, log=True),
    'min_data_in_leaf': trial.suggest_int('min_data_in_leaf', 20, 100),
    'reg_alpha': trial.suggest_float('reg_alpha', 1e-2, 10.0, log=True),
    'reg_lambda': trial.suggest_float('reg_lambda', 1e-2, 10.0, log=True),
    'scale_pos_weight': class_weights[0] / class_weights[1] * 1.5,
    'max_bin': trial.suggest_int('max_bin', 150, 255),
    'bagging_freq': trial.suggest_int('bagging_freq', 3, 10)

However, after installing LightGBM with GPU support (version 4.5.0), I started encountering the following error during some trials:
lightgbm.basic.LightGBMError: Check failed: (best_split_info.left_count) > (0) at /__w/1/s/lightgbm-python/src/treelearner/serial_tree_learner.cpp, line 846 in some trials.

The code is exactly the same. The only difference is the Lgbm model and the device from cpu to gpu.
Why is this happening?
LGBM version is 4.5.0.
EDIT:
Successful Trial:
[I 2024-12-26 20:08:39,966] Trial 0 finished with value: 0.8819786375246853 and parameters: {'max_depth': 17, 'num_leaves': 205, 'learning_rate': 0.09026914575154911, 'feature_fraction': 0.7398149462639332, 'bagging_fraction': 0.5564346894052175, 'min_data_in_leaf': 78, 'reg_alpha': 3.6603460275431643, 'reg_lambda': 6.889417388456112, 'max_bin': 220, 'bagging_freq': 10, 'min_split_gain': 1.0}. Best is trial 0 with value: 0.8819786375246853.
2024-12-26 20:08:39,979 - INFO - 
Starting Trial 1
2024-12-26 20:08:40,046 - INFO - Trial 1 - Using parameters: {'objective': 'binary', 'metric': 'auc', 'boosting_type': 'gbdt', 'verbosity': -1, 'device': 'gpu', 'max_depth': 19, 'num_leaves': 159, 'learning_rate': 0.04298456675770763, 'feature_fraction': 0.798899427695295, 'bagging_fraction': 0.8745605272424055, 'min_data_in_leaf': 50, 'reg_alpha': 0.01828714113213478, 'reg_lambda': 0.016787101660128333, 'scale_pos_weight': 0.054386777838402504, 'max_bin': 226, 'bagging_freq': 6, 'min_split_gain': 1.0, 'min_sum_hessian_in_leaf': 0, 'min_child_samples': 1, 'min_child_weight': 2.64588762915239e-06}
Training until validation scores don't improve for 100 rounds
Early stopping, best iteration is:
[200]   valid_0's auc: 0.913048
Training until validation scores don't improve for 100 rounds
Early stopping, best iteration is:
[214]   valid_0's auc: 0.913893
Training until validation scores don't improve for 100 rounds
Early stopping, best iteration is:
[204]   valid_0's auc: 0.918618
Training until validation scores don't improve for 100 rounds
Early stopping, best iteration is:
[227]   valid_0's auc: 0.908563
Training until validation scores don't improve for 100 rounds
Early stopping, best iteration is:
[202]   valid_0's auc: 0.909499

Failed Trial:
2024-12-26 20:22:36,408 - INFO - Trial 15 - Using parameters: {'objective': 'binary', 'metric': 'auc', 'boosting_type': 'gbdt', 'verbosity': -1, 'device': 'gpu', 'max_depth': 14, 'num_leaves': 191, 'learning_rate': 0.031937186167152284, 'feature_fraction': 0.7890081529223356, 'bagging_fraction': 0.9878259799656386, 'min_data_in_leaf': 34, 'reg_alpha': 0.16390851440880908, 'reg_lambda': 0.15367896667113654, 'scale_pos_weight': 0.054386777838402504, 'max_bin': 207, 'bagging_freq': 8, 'min_split_gain': 1.0, 'min_sum_hessian_in_leaf': 0, 'min_child_samples': 1, 'min_child_weight': 2.64588762915239e-06}
Training until validation scores don't improve for 100 rounds
Early stopping, best iteration is:
[255]   valid_0's auc: 0.908281
Training until validation scores don't improve for 100 rounds
Early stopping, best iteration is:
[259]   valid_0's auc: 0.910945
Training until validation scores don't improve for 100 rounds
[LightGBM] [Fatal] Check failed: (best_split_info.left_count) > (0) at /__w/1/s/lightgbm-python/src/treelearner/serial_tree_learner.cpp, line 846 .

[W 2024-12-26 20:23:12,516] Trial 15 failed with parameters: {'max_depth': 14, 'num_leaves': 191, 'learning_rate': 0.031937186167152284, 'feature_fraction': 0.7890081529223356, 'bagging_fraction': 0.9878259799656386, 'min_data_in_leaf': 34, 'reg_alpha': 0.16390851440880908, 'reg_lambda': 0.15367896667113654, 'max_bin': 207, 'bagging_freq': 8, 'min_split_gain': 1.0} because of the following error: LightGBMError('Check failed: (best_split_info.left_count) > (0) at /__w/1/s/lightgbm-python/src/treelearner/serial_tree_learner.cpp, line 846 .\n').
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/thkast/Desktop/fraud_master_final/myenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/optuna/study/_optimize.py", line 196, in _run_trial
    value_or_values = func(trial)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/thkast/Desktop/fraud_master_final/2_Train_LG_utils copy.py", line 124, in <lambda>
    lambda trial: objective_lgbm(
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/thkast/Desktop/fraud_master_final/utils/utils.py", line 512, in objective_lgbm
    model = lgb.train(
            ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/thkast/Desktop/fraud_master_final/myenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/lightgbm/engine.py", line 307, in train
    booster.update(fobj=fobj)
  File "/home/thkast/Desktop/fraud_master_final/myenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/lightgbm/basic.py", line 4135, in update
    _safe_call(
  File "/home/thkast/Desktop/fraud_master_final/myenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/lightgbm/basic.py", line 296, in _safe_call
    raise LightGBMError(_LIB.LGBM_GetLastError().decode("utf-8"))
lightgbm.basic.LightGBMError: Check failed: (best_split_info.left_count) > (0) at /__w/1/s/lightgbm-python/src/treelearner/serial_tree_learner.cpp, line 846 .


This GitHub issue suggests trying min_split_gain=1 as a work-around. Another suggestion there is min_child_sample=1, min_child_weight=1/X_train.shape[0]. Seems like it's associated with larger datasets, so worth trying a batched approach using init_model=, or training with a smaller dataset.

@MuhammedYunusStopTheGenocide I tried it but I am receiving the same issue again.

If you make the dataset a lot smaller (e.g. just a few tens/hundreds of samples), does it still error? Trying a previous version of LightGBM might help. I think there's an option in Optuna ("verbose"?) to find out the trial it is failing for - might be a bad hyperparameter combination.

@MuhammedYunusStopTheGenocide I have enabled verbosity in my trials, and I've noticed that the failure is not consistent across all trials or folds. It specifically occurs in certain folds. If this were a hyperparameter issue, wouldn't it fail consistently across all folds rather than proceeding successfully in one or two?
I have edited my first post, with some logs.

Yeah if it was a hyperparameter issue I'd expect it to fail for all CV folds of a trial, rather than just for a single fold (I think there could be edge cases though). If you are able to provide a sample of the data, I can try replicating the problem. Another thing to try is: disable all the hyperparameters except one, and see if it's a particular hyperparameter that it fails for. To make things simpler, it might help to run the code manually whilst you're debugging rather than in Optuna.
